# Программа по определению прогрессии

Tags: c#

Ниже представлен полный код, на выводе в экран всегда пишет, что последовательность является и той и той прогрессией. Не могу понять в чем ошибка.

```
    static void definition(double[] Mass,int Elements)
    {
        double d = Mass[Elements -1] - Mass[Elements - 2];
        double q = Mass[Elements -1] / Mass[Elements - 2];
        int count1 = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Elements; i++)
        {
            if (Mass[i] == Mass[0] + d * (i - 1))
            {
                count1++;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (Mass[i] == Mass[0] * Math.Pow(q, i - 1))
            {
                count2++;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (count1 == count2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nДанная прогрессия является и арифметической и геометрической");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else if (count2 == Elements)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nЭто геометрическая прогрессия");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else if (count1 == Elements)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nЭто арифметическая прогрессия ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nДанная последовательность не является ни одной из прогрессий");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите кол-во символов:");
        int numberofE = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        // Проверка на кол-во элементов
        if (numberofE <= 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Это не является последовательностью, запустите программу снова");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            double[] sequence = new double[numberofE];
            for (int i = 0; i < numberofE; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введите {0}-е число", i + 1);

                sequence[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Ваш набор чисел:");
            for (int i = 0; i < numberofE; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(sequence[i]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            definition(sequence, numberofE);
        }
        
        
    }
```

Comment: *`double q = Mass[Elements -1] / Mass[Elements - 2];`* Не боитесь поделить на ноль? *`if (count1 == count2)`* А с количеством элементов сравнивать кто будет? а то ить фигня получится...

Comment: Справедливо. Спасибо, учту.

Answer (score 1):

Выведите в консоль `count1` и `count2` и поймете.

---

`... (i - 1))` - почему "минус один"?

---

`Mass[i] == ...` - точная проверка на равенство чисел с плавающей точкой редко работает как ожидается.

Comment: 'count1' и 'count2' равны 0 как и ожидалось, в таком случае почему не щелкается счетчик? (i-1) - потому что формула прогрессии an =  a1 + d ( n – 1 ) , где n=i. А как же в прогрессии выполнять проверку без точного равенства? Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛеонов Что значит "щелкается счетчик"? И почему "как и ожидалось"? Я думал, что Вы ожидали правильных результатов. Вы перепутали номера членов прогрессии при натуральном счете и их индексы в массиве.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛеонов Без точного равенства надо использовать приблизительное - с заданной точностью.